# PHP exec ffmpeg convert results in 500 Internal Server Error muxing overhead

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I'm using Windows Server 2016

This is the PHP code I use:

```
exec('"' . $ffmpeg . '" -y -i "' . $inputFile . '" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -to ' . $till . ' "' . $temp . '" 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
```

It works but after that I get `500 Internal Server Error` which lasts about 2 - 3 seconds.

I tried to change `2>&1` to `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664011/php-internal-server-error-500-when-using-ffmpeg-to-convert-files) answer so:

```
exec('"' . $ffmpeg . '" -y -i "' . $inputFile . '" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -to ' . $till . ' "' . $temp . '" > /dev/null 2>&1 &', $output, $return_var);
```

but now the conversion doesn't work any more.

EDIT:

I should add that the 500 Internal Server Error doesn't happen when I run the script but when I open the website within 2 - 3 seconds after conversion

Comment: Can you echo the complete exec string? Maybe someone can find in error in user ffmpeg?

Comment: You mean echo $output? Because echo exec('"' . $ffmpeg . '" -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -to ' . $till . ' finish.mp4 > /dev/null &', $output, $return_var); doesn't show anything

Comment: @Marco but echo the old way: echo exec('"' . $ffmpeg . '" -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -to ' . $till . ' finish.mp4 2>&1', $output, $return_var); shows: video:77kB audio:178kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 7.572839%

Comment: hmm... It seems to run, but are you quite sure, that the internal server error occurs within the exec?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it by only having this in a PHP file @Marco

Comment: The linked post indicate that your issue is php timing out while waiting for ffmpeg to finish the job. The OP fixed it by "execut[ing] the php script using the php-cli command with a scheduled cron job" (however way it is as I don't know php)

Comment: Hmm I can't imagine it having anything to do with timing out since the conversion only takes 2 seconds max @kesh